# Stochastic Task Processing Times in Queueing Theory

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing, operations-research

I'm struggling with an operations research problem which has 3 stations containing 3 different task processing times and different coefficients of variation (for example, station 1 has 3 tasks with having coefficients of variation 1,0.5 and 0.75). I am asked to calculate the average waiting times in the flow line and individual stations. The cycle time is assumed to be constant and the flow line follows a synced push policy with constant WIP. How do I approach this? I am supposed to state the assumptions for inter-arrival times as well.